# ApplicationBar is a type but is used as a variable in Panorama view

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make a localized application bar in panorama view's code behind. Here's my code:

```
// Helper function to build a localized ApplicationBar
        private void BuildApplicationBar()
        {
            // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

            // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
            ApplicationBarIconButton homeButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/icons_home.png", UriKind.Relative));
            homeButton.Text = AppResources.HomeIcon;
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(homeButton);
            homeButton.Click += new EventHandler(HomeButton_Click);

            ApplicationBarIconButton searchButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/appbar.feature.search.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
            searchButton.Text = AppResources.SearchIcon;
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(searchButton);
            searchButton.Click += new EventHandler(SearchButton_Click);
        }
```

However, it doesn't recognize my ApplicationBar as a property. The error says: 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar' is a 'type' but is used as a 'variable'. Any idea why? Thanks very much!

Fei

Comment: So what exact type are you deriving from?

Comment: Is it a type? If it's a propriety try renaming. If, say, Mode is a static propriety, make sure it's public.

Comment: @fei-qu Btw, it would be nice if you selected answer as best or commented any new problems. Might motivate more people to answer future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your propriety has the same name as the type it has. Rename it. So:

```
ApplicationBar ApplicationBar
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

to

```
ApplicationBar MyApplicationBar
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

and

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
```

to

```
this.MyApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
```

and any other reference to the propriety to `this.MyApplicationBar`

Comment: Hi Shingetsu, thanks for your reply. But actually I just made a stupid mistake. I put that method in another class in that file instead of code-behind class. ;-P